# how to get value of the attribute of tag in template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular5, angular6

how to get **value** of the attribute of tag in template and store it in
            variable in typescript. 
            for that I tried with the code below but I am getting error

**template**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of store">
<div (click)='getMatchid("value")'   value={{item.ttypeUid}} >{{item.ttypeName}}</div>
              </div>
```

**typecsript**

```
  getMatchid(val){
    this.MatchId = val
    console.log('val ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ' + val);

  }
```

Comment: Can you please add more details about your problem?

Comment: A valid `div` doesn't have a `value` attribute. There is no point in setting `value={{item.ttypeUid}}`.

Comment: Check my answer sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly pass ttypeUid to getMachid like

```
<div (click)='getMatchid(item.ttypeUid)'>{{item.ttypeName})</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **value attribute is for input**,It is not available in a `div`

Pass the Id as an argument in the function itself like this,

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of store">
    <div (click)='getMatchid(item.ttypeUi)'>
         {{item.ttypeName}}
    </div>  
</div>
```

TS

```
 getMatchid(val){
    this.MatchId = val
    console.log('val ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ' + val);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get ttypeUid on click of div then
you can write as follows

**HTML code**

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of store">
     <div (click)='getMatchid(item.ttypeUid)'>{{item.ttypeName}}</div>
   </div>
```

**TS Code**

```
getMatchid(val){
  // you will get here, val == item.ttypeUid
  this.MatchId = val
   console.log('val ++++' + val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of store">
    <div (click)="getMatchid(item.ttypeUid)">{{item.ttypeName}}</div>
</div>



getMatchid(val){
    this.MatchId = val;
    console.log(val, '*** Value From Div Click ***');
}
```